# Set up the interpreter in PyCharm with WSL Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, pycharm

I added this descriptor to `wsl.distributions.xml` in the `[pycharm]/config/options` directory:

```
 <descriptor>
        <id>Ubuntu-20.04</id>
        <microsoft-id>Ubuntu-20.04</microsoft-id>
        <executable-path>C:\Windows\System32\lxss\wslhost.exe</executable-path>
        <presentable-name>Ubuntu-20.04</presentable-name>
</descriptor>
```

When I go to set up the interpreter in PyCharm, choose [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) and, it finds the correct version and `/usr/bin/python` points to the correct WSL package (the same package in the [Windows Registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) under lsxx).

However, when I click OK I get this error:

> Process finished with exit code 1

Why? Or how can I debug this with logs?

[image: Error]

Comment: I would delete whatever that custom xml you wrote is ... for me i just selected wsl and selected my distribution and python instance ... if its not identifying your wsl environment that is what i would try to fix

Comment: doesn't work. it doesn't find ubuntu 20.04 and asks to install a windows app, as you say the solution is likely to install Ubuntu app instead of 20.04 app. Just don't want to give up yet

Answer (score 0):

You should check the existence of the interpreter path at Ubuntu 20.04: `ls /usr/bin/python`. I suppose it should be replaced with `/usr/bin/python3`. The path may depend on the installed Python version.

I checked it on my own system and it worked. Also, my descriptor looks like this:

```
<descriptor>
  <id>UBUNTU2004</id>
  <microsoft-id>Ubuntu-20.04</microsoft-id>
  <executable-path>ubuntu2004.exe</executable-path>
  <presentable-name>Ubuntu 20.04</presentable-name>
</descriptor>
```